# postfix: forward all mail except local user ones

Tags: postfix, smtp

I have a website on a server with a postfix mail server to send the site's emails. Let's say the domain is example.com.

The site can send mails to mailboxes of his own domain (like contact@example.com), which is hosted on another server and to any other domains.

As I don't want any local delivery, even for example.com, the mydestination parameter is empty.

This worked great, but I can't redirect mails to local users.
For example, if `mdadm` send a mail to `root`, the mail will be sent to root@example.com directly, without going throw /etc/aliases.

How can I deliver localy mails to local users, and keep sending mails to mailboxes @example.com?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use localhost for `mydestination` and `myorigin`

```
mydestination = localhost
myorigin = localhost
```

With this setup, when `mdadm` send email to `root`, it will transformed to `root@localhost`. With `mydestination = localhost`, postfix will consult `/etc/aliases` to do aliasing.

If you aren't comfortable with root@localhost in `return-path`, then you can use smtp_generic_maps to repair it

```
#main.cf
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/rewrite

#/etc/postfix/rewrite
localhost example.com
```

Comment: Your solution works, but the mail headers now contains localhost instead of example.com : I get Return-Path: <colin@localhost> instead of Return-Path: <colin@example.com> for mail sent by the user colin.

Comment: See updated answer